# Android Custom TextView class -how to reuse it as a custom EditText view

Tags: inheritance, android-edittext, android

I have created a customTextView java class which looks like this more or less:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}
```

}

in xml i'd use it like this:

```
 <com.mypackage.mystyles.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/myid"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="hello world this is a tv" />
```

but i would also like to make a custom EditTextView with very similar overrided behavior and be able to make a call like this:

```
<com.mypackage.mystyles.CustomEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_id"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="hello world this is a et" />
```

how can i use the same java class (CustomTextView.java in my case)  as i dont want to repeat code as really EditText is a subclass of TextView.

Comment: You have little choice but to either repeat your code or the code in `EditText` if you want something that combines both.

Answer (score 0):

I found a interesting way to accomplish this an reuse the code.  In oncreate i would call a method i made called applyMyOwnFonts()

and then i would override the inflater to set my own customization on each view:

```
public void applyMyOwnFonts() {
    getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
                AttributeSet attrs) {
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("TextView")
                    || name.equalsIgnoreCase("Button")
                    || name.equalsIgnoreCase("EditText")
                    || name.equalsIgnoreCase("RadioButton"){
                    LayoutInflater f = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs);
                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            MyCustomTextView.doWhatIneedToDo(view); //static call
                        }
                    });
                    return view;

            }
            return null;
        }

    });
}
```

so any textviews, buttons, edittexts and radiobuttons could forexample have all the same fonts or same text size etc.  its like over riding the frameworks defaults.